# terraform-aws ecs: Terminate ecs instances when renaming ecs cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When I rename an ECS cluster terraform times out while waiting for the cluster to be destroyed.

```
module.ecs.aws_ecs_cluster.main: Still destroying... (ID: arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:123456789:ecs-cluster, 10m47s elapsed)
```

The issue is that EC2 instances are not terminated. Once I manually terminate them, terraform is able to continue as usual. These instances were started by an auto-scaling group.

I think there is no dependency from these EC2 instances to the terraform managed resource, so the instances are not being deleted.

What should I do to make terraform "see" these instances?

Comment: You'll need to show your existing Terraform code but the answer is going to be that for Terraform to follow the dependency between the resources they need to be in the same directory so they can be applied together.

Comment: They are in the same directory. No module or otherwise. The thing i am trying to figure out is how does Terraform reference variable number of EC2 instances? ASG will create or terminate instances depending on my scaling parameters.

Comment: You need to show your Terraform code if you want anyone to be able to point out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: If your instance have termination protection, then the cluster will not destroy. Or there is anything created with termination protection or if there are resources created manually or through a script outside of terraform.